# Ansible ansible.builtin.package variable substitution

Tags: debian, rhel, package-management, ansible

Following the example here;
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_module.html#examples

```
# This uses a variable as this changes per distribution.
- name: Remove the apache package
  ansible.builtin.package:
    name: "{{ apache }}"
    state: absent
```

I cannot see how you would make that variable distinguish OS. how would I define that variable to be `apache` or `httpd` based on distro?

I know how to make plays based on distro but not with variable substitution as per above, like so;

```
---
- name: Upgrade packages
  hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Update all packages to the latest version Debian
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        update_cache: yes
        cache_valid_time: 3600
        upgrade: full
      when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == "Debian"

    - name: Update all packages to the latest version RedHat
      ansible.builtin.dnf:
        update_cache: yes
        name: "*"
        state: latest
      when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == "RedHat"
```

I am trying to avoid creating a whole new task each time as the only difference will be the package name to install, the rest of the role I am creating is idempotent across OS types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cannot see how you would make that variable distinguish OS. how would I define that variable to be apache or httpd based on distro?

There are lots of options.

A simple solution is to use the [`vars_files`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html) section of your play, and have it load a variable file based on the operating system name.  For example:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  vars_files:
    - "vars/{{ ansible_os_family|lower }}.yaml"
  tasks:
    - name: Remove the apache package
      ansible.builtin.package:
        name: "{{ apache }}"
        state: absent
```

This uses the value of `ansible_os_family`, which is provided by
Ansible's fact gathering support. Given the above tasks, you might
have a file `vars/redhat.yaml` that contains:

```
apache: httpd
```

Or a file `vars/debian.yaml` that contains:

```
apache: apache2
```

You could use `ansible_distribution` instead of `ansible_os_family` if
you need more granularity (e.g., `ansible_os_family` will be `Redhat` under Fedora, CentOS, Red Hat, etc, whereas `ansible_distribution` has the name of the specific distribution).

---

If you want to do this as part of a role, you can do something similar using the [`include_vars` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html). See [the examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html#examples) in the documentation:

```
- name: Load a variable file based on the OS type, or a default if not found. Using free-form to specify the file.
  ansible.builtin.include_vars: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.first_found', params) }}"
  vars:
    params:
      files:
        - '{{ansible_distribution}}.yaml'
        - '{{ansible_os_family}}.yaml'
        - default.yaml
      paths:
        - 'vars'
```